# Scaled iframe takes up extra space

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am linking a rating program to my site. The iframe is great on desktop but needs some help on mobile. I scaled the content down so the user could see everything, but now I have extra spacing on the right.

This is my code:

```css
.quoteIframerapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  height:500px;
}
.quoteIframe{
  height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .quoteIframerapper{
    width:153.84615385%;
  }
  .quoteIframe{
    -moz-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -o-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quoteIframerapper">
   <iframe class="quoteIframe" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.agentinsure.com/compare/auto-insurance-home-insurance/hillinsurance/quote.aspx"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the `.quoteIframe`, so that you cut down the free space Like this:

```css
.quoteIframerapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  height:500px;
}
.quoteIframe{
  height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .quoteIframerapper{
    width:153.84615385%;
  }
  .quoteIframe{
    width: 48%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -o-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quoteIframerapper">
   <iframe class="quoteIframe" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.agentinsure.com/compare/auto-insurance-home-insurance/hillinsurance/quote.aspx"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: Well, the content of the iframe is restricted to 515px width.This will alwasy leave some space on the right side. Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve here? You want the iframe to be the same width as your page or? Even if you make it full width here, the embeded page has white space itself. Also, where do you want the scrollbar of the iframe to be?

Comment: Take a look on a mobile device and you will see what I mean. simon.barretthillins.com

Comment: You need to set `overflow: hidden` to the parent of the iframe.

Comment: Are you sure? I've set it on the `.quote-box` which is the parent of the parent of `.quoteIframerapper` and it removes the extra space (via the browser inspector). The extra space is coming from the iframe. Usually iframes have widths and heights and you have to restrict them to the container, where you put it by setting their width to 100% and add overflow:hidden; to the parent

Comment: Another issue is that `.cpMainBoxWrapper` in the iframe document has width of 515px; That needs to be changed on a lower resolutions. Maybe that is the original cause of the problem. So try to change it and see what happens

Comment: Thanks @martin. That did it! I set it in .quoteIframerapper. Totally forgot about .quote-box. Also just realized the typo, rapper lol. Could I get rid of quoteIframerapper and put the css in quote-box? And lastly, I cannot edit the css for .cpMainBoxWrapper. Thats why I was scaling it down to start with.

Comment: Glad I helped. Yes you can get rid of that wrapper div if  that's the only reason why you put it.